# -bash: test.out: command not found

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Visual Studio 2017 C++ project that deploys to a Beaglebone Black Debian 9.2.

I can run it in debug mode and see the output in the console.

I can SSH into the device and run it from the path `/home/steve/projects/BBB2/bin/ARM/Debug/BBB2.out`

but when I'm in that directory and try to run it by just using `BBB2.out` I get a `-bash: BBB2.out: command not found` message.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the directory your BB2.out file is in, is not part of the system's path.  You can get past this by prepending `./` to the command (`./BB2.out`) when you run it.

Alternately, you can add the current directory to your path so that the system will always recognise the directory you are in as being able to run executables.

This will add the current directory to the end of the path:

`export PATH=$PATH:.`

However there is a potential security risk here as documented in this [unix faq](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html).

Comment: This does work. I'm a windows guy so it's kinda hard to understand why it can't find the file in the directory that I'm currently in. Seems like a hassle to add every folder to PATH, so I guess this is standard practice to run executables that aren't installed?

Comment: The dot-slash-executable procedure is fairly standard.  A lot of home linux users will use the `export PATH` line, so that any directory they are currently in will be included in the path.  Another user option is to create a bin directory in your user directory (/home/usernam/bin) and put all executables there.  For the why, *nix systems expect certain files to be in certain places - binaries (executables) are generally in a `bin` directory (of course that could be `/bin` or `/usr/bin`).  [File System Info](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html)